# googleapi: 403: The download quota for this file has been exceeded. Creds are good, file is new

Tags: google-drive-api

Please note, this issue seems unique from other "quota exceeded" issues I've seen. It's not bad creds, and it's not a file that has been downloaded a lot.

```
2020/02/21 15:44:49 ERROR : test.mkv: Failed to copy: multpart copy: failed to open source: open file failed: googleapi: Error 403: The download quota for this file has been exceeded., downloadQuotaExceeded
```

1. I'm only receiving this error through the API.
2. Other files in this shared drive are accessible with the same credentials.
3. This doesn't affect the file for other users (ie: I tested with an actual Google account [rather than a Service Account] and was able to download the file via the UI.

So what can be going on? I'm used to 403s with Google APIs when the user doesn't have permission, and have even seen this "reason" in a scenario where I just hadn't granted permissions yet. But in this case, the permissions seem just fine [they're all set at the Drive level, anyway].

Important context:

1. The files that are having this problem were copied from... public sources. Those files likely *have* exceeded their download quota. But these are copies that I made into my own drive.
2. To be more speciic, I have copied files into my Drive via the web UI and these files have never presented an issue.
3. However, these new files that are having issues - I copied them via the Drive API. But they say they're owned by my Service Account, and I can't find ANY linkage back to the original file they were copied from. Just like when I copy them by hand, they have their own file IDs, different than the ones they were copied from.

Things I'm suspicious of:

1. Maybe the copy performed via the UI, and the copy performed by the API are somehow different?
2. Somehow my "copy" of the file is more strongly linked to the original file I copied from originally?

Otherwise, I'm out of ideas. Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

EDIT:

Manual copy method: File file, add star to it, navigate to Drive web ui, go to Starred items, right-click on the file, "Make a Copy".

New API method: use Rust to do this:

```rust
let url = format!("https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/{}/copy", file_id);

let auth_hdr_val = format!("Bearer {}", token.as_str());
let mut query_params = HashMap::new();
query_params.insert("supportsAllDrives", true);
query_params.insert("supportsTeamDrives", true);

let mut body = HashMap::new();
body.insert("parents", [destination_parent_dir]);

client
    .post(&url)
    .query(&query_params)
    .header(reqwest::header::AUTHORIZATION, auth_hdr_val)
    .json(&body)
    .send()
```

Nothing too wild, just calling the v3 drive copy API, with a parent directory specified which is a Shared Drive. (Seems like it also happens if I API copy to my drive first, then manually move to Shared Drive.)

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? About `these new files that are having issues - I copied them via the Drive API.`, can you provide the detail information? Are you using a script or a curl command or other method? I thought that when you provide the detail method for replicating your issue, it might help users think of the issue and solution. But if I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: Tanaike, of course, that's a great question - I should have included that. I have now editted it to include the details about how I've copied these files, both manually and my new way. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. `file_id` is a file ID of the file you want to copy. `token.as_str()` is the valid access token retrieved from OAuth2 or service account. Is my understanding correct? In your case, if the access token cannot be correctly used, such error might occur. At first, please confirm this again. And, for example, in your case, when you want to download a publicly shared file, if `query_params` is removed, what result will you get?

Comment: Correct. The problem cannot be with the auth, since the file is in fact being copied into the drive. If I remove query_params, nothing should happen as those both default to true, but I can try.

I've also done some more testing. No matter how I copy this file (even via UI) I can't download via API, but I can download via the browser. Quite strange!

Comment: @Tanaike, I've discovered the problem/solution and posted it as an answer. Thank you for your questions, they helped me get there.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Drive has undocumented API limits. It appears that one of them is a per-user, per-file limitation.

I switched the service account that I was using to download the particularly problematic files, and they downloaded successfully.

It appears that the "new" method was not the problem, but rather that another service was indexing "new" files in Google Drive and bumped up against this limit. The service account used for downloading was shared with the one indexing.

So, avoid hitting these limits, or use different service accounts for different roles, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I know you found a workaround for your issue, but it seems the issue you were having, it was previously reported by other people on [Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker):

- ["downloadQuotaExceeded": The download quota for this file has been exceeded.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64007788).
- [Receiving downloadQuotaExceeded error in python client](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/71874148).

You can hit the ☆ next to the issue number in the top left on this page as it lets Google know more people are encountering this and so it is more likely to be seen to faster.